# Issue with code changing when I pull from github on Android Studio?

Tags: java, git, android-studio, github

I just updated my master branch, and I can see the code on GitHub and it looks exactly how it should. However, when I try to "update project" or "pull" on android studio, I seem to be getting different code than on GitHub, which is preventing it from compiling.

Of course I've made sure I'm on the right branch and everything. I've tried deleting the project and checking it out again. I've tried updating and reinstalling Android Studio. I've tried to hard reset to a previous commit that I know was functional. Nothing seems to make a difference. The code I get is always different from the code I have on GitHub.

Comment: it is all a bit vague... and not really [java] - if you are sure "on the right branch and **everything**" then its hard to do anything. It would be easier to know what is wrong knowing what is the difference or/and how you know it is different (maybe even which Github repository)

Comment: When you do git pull did you got any merging issues

Answer (score 0):

You are probably hitting the wrong repository
try this command and compare it to the actual GitHub url :

```
git config --get remote.origin.url
```